# why .box width rendered as 139px but 120px?

Tags: html, css, input

[the result capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3bF4Y.png)

go to [codepen](https://codepen.io/happy-func/pen/JjxzoxE?editors=1100) to see the result online

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.box{
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  min-width: 24px;
}
.input{
  min-width: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
  background: transparent;
  outline: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
}
.text{
  min-width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <input class="input" />
  <div class="text">Text</div>
</div>
```

`.box` should be render width as 120px, what happened?

Comment: _"what happend?"_ - `<input>` happened. _That_ one comes with a default width of 139px here, and therefor of course extends the width of `.box`. And since `.text` is a div with only a min-width specified, it of course still stretches over the whole available `.box` width.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#size: _"size:
Valid for email, password, tel, url, and text, the size attribute specifies how much of the input is shown. Basically creates same result as setting CSS width property with a few specialities. The actual unit of the value depends on the input type. For password and text, it is a number of characters (or em units) with a default value of 20, and for others, it is pixels (or px units)."_ - you did not _specify_ a size for your input field, so you get one made wide enough to take 20 characters of input.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `min-width: 24px;` to `width: 120px;` in the .box class.
This will set the width from the box to 120px.

Comment: yeah, but In the UI design, the width of the `.box` and `.input` should be determined by `.text`.Sorry I didn't make it clear in the question